# Godot, can't make functioning buttons in a class constructor

Tags: button, godot, godot4

I'm trying to make a button within a class constructor in Godot 4. Making them outside works like normal, but when I do it inside a class constructor, pressing them does not run the function connected to them.

Example code for the class:

```
class test_class:

    func _init(parent):
        var test_button = Button.new()
        test_button.text = "Click me!"
        test_button.connect("pressed",_test_function)
        parent.add_child(test_button)

    func _test_function():
        print("hello")
```

The button appears when the code is run, and displays the graphical changes of being clicked, but the function does not run. How could I make it run?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a similar issue, maybe have a read:

[connect function](https://ask.godotengine.org/64268/connect-function-in-a-class-to-create-a-interactive-button)